# Why is my iterator not std::input_iterator?

Tags: c++, c++20

Why doesn't the iterator below satisfy `std::input_iterator` concept? What did I miss?

```
template <class T>
struct IteratorSentinel {};

template <class T>
class Iterator
{
public:

    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    using value_type = T;

    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    using pointer = value_type*;

    using reference = value_type&;

    Iterator() = default;
    
    Iterator(const Iterator&) = delete;

    Iterator& operator = (const Iterator&) = delete;

    Iterator(Iterator&& other) = default;

    Iterator& operator = (Iterator&& other) = default;

    T* operator-> ();

    T& operator* ();

    bool operator== (const IteratorSentinel<T>&) const noexcept;

    Iterator& operator++ ();

    void operator++ (int);
};
```

The following static assertion fails:

```
static_assert(std::input_iterator<Iterator<int>>);
```

And, for example, the code below does not compile:

```
template <class T>
auto make_range()
{
    return std::ranges::subrange(Iterator<T>(), IteratorSentinel<T>{});
}

std::ranges::equal(make_range<int>(), std::vector<int>());
```

Comment: My Clang gives me `constraints not satisfied for alias template 'iter_reference_t' [with _Tp = const Iterator<int>]`, meaning `operator*` must work even on const iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator*` is not `const`-qualified.

The `std::input_iterator` concept (through the `std::indirectly_readable` concept) requires that `*` can be applied to both `const` and non-`const` lvalues as well as rvalues of the type and that in all cases the same type is returned.

Comment: Adding `const T& operator* () const` does not help.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky "_and that in all cases the same type is returned_". It must return `T&`, not `const T&`.